# iOS6 app updating to iOS7 receipt

Tags: iphone, security, ios7, storekit

I am updating an old app that used the old iOS6 purchase receipt verification method (ie: `[SKPaymentTransaction -transactionReceipt]`).

In the new version, I would like to use the new `[NSBundle -appStoreReceiptURL]` method to support restoration for old customers. For users who simply update our app, is there an app receipt automatically installed by the system or do we need to use `SKReceiptRefreshRequest` to get a new receipt? In the `SKReceiptRefreshRequest` documentation it talks about the sandbox environment only. In live code, what is the purpose of this class?

Also, I do not understand the conditions when a receipt is "Revoked" or "Expired".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not quite clear when exactly the iOS7 app receipt is generated. 
It probably is generated when the app is downloaded or a purchase is made. 
In the case of an app update I'm not sure what happens.

To be sure, you should implement `SKReceiptRefreshRequest` anyway. This request returns (or creates if not available) the app receipt. I haven't seen anywhere stated that it is only for sandbox.

Revoked and Expired are only used in Volume Purchase Plans receipts I believe.

Comment: What about the bundle version inside the receipt? Is this automatically updated or not? So badly documented here

Comment: Also curious about this.  If a user installed my app on ios6, then upgrades to ios7, will the app then have a receipt, and **will the receipt contain the "original application version" field** that seems to be the only way to find out if a paid-to-freemium upgrade should be eligible for in-app features.